# How to avoid for loops in this code to improve computation time

Tags: matlab, performance

In this code, I have a cluster image with 10 classes and i want to extract 10 different images for each level and save as a 10 images Below is the code, I used

```
tic
numberOfClasses = 10;
segment_label_images = cell(1,numberOfClasses);
pixelCount = zeros(1,numberOfClasses);
[rs, cs] = size(classImage);
% classImage has intensity range from 1-numberOfClasses
for k = 1:numberOfClasses
    for i = 1:rs
        for j = 1:cs
            if classImage(i,j) == k
                segment_label_images{k}(i,j) = 1;
            else
                segment_label_images{k}(i,j) = 0;
            end
        end
    end
pixelCount(k) = sum(segment_label_images{k}(:));
%figure, imshow(segment_label_images{k},[]);
end
toc
```

Here, I have 3 for loops and I think that is affecting computational time. Elapsed time is 0.089413 seconds.

Any suggestions to avoid for loop to improve comp time.? Thanks, Gopi

Comment: For performance don't use cell arrays. Use 3D array IMG(i,j,N) for grayscale images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `classImage` is a matrix you could speed it up with

```
for k = 1:numberOfClasses
    segment_label_images{k} = classImage == k;
    pixelCount(k) = sum(segment_label_images{k}(:));
end
```

Comment: Thanks flawr, It worked very fast and improved computation speed by 3-4 times. and yes classImage is a matrix

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MATLAB 2016b (or Octave):

```
k = permute(1:numberOfClasses, [1,3,2]);
segment_label_images = (classImage == k);
pixelCount = squeeze(sum(sum(segment_label_images, 1), 2));
```

For pre-2016b MATLAB, just add `bsxfun`:

```
k = permute(1:numberOfClasses, [1,3,2]);
segment_label_images = bsxfun(@eq, classImage, k);
pixelCount = squeeze(sum(sum(segment_label_images, 1), 2));
```

Of course, both of these leave `segment_label_images` as a 3D array rather than a cell array. Given that all of the arrays are the same size, I prefer to work with multi-dimensional arrays rather than cell arrays, for speed and convenience. It can, of course, be converted to a cell array if necessary.